# Don't match white space after word, but include when part of bigger string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
\b(?!^Word1$|^Word2$|^Word3$|^Word4$)\b(?![\s]+)[a-zA-Z0-9\']{2,}
```

When a user types 'Word1' it doesn't match, which is what I want. When the user types 'Word1 foo' the whole string matches again, which is what I want.

However, when user types 'Word1 ' (note the space) the string matches. I'd like it to remain unmatched until another word is typed and then the whole line is matched.

Comment: Do it like `^Word1\s?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iS6rV3/1)

Very basic regex:

```
\w+[\s\w]*\w
```

It should match `word` and not `word`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression works only for strings with more than 1 word

```
\w*\s\w*
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Gops beat you to the answer.